# Get text from ListView and send it to editText of another activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

Two classes are there-Voice.java and TranslateActivity.java. I want text clicked on list View to be converted into string and passed into edit Text of Translate Activity.java . But in my code as I click on list View for selecting,Application crashes.
Classes are: 
Voice.java

```
package com.example.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class Voice extends Activity implements OnClickListener,OnItemClickListener{

    ListView lv;
    static final int check=1111;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.voice);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bVoice);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        Intent i=new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak Up");
        startActivityForResult(i, check);   
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(requestCode == check && resultCode==RESULT_OK){

            ArrayList<String> results=data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
            }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) arg1).getText(),
    //            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  ListView button = (ListView) arg1;
        String st= lv.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Bundle basket=new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key",st);
        Intent a=new Intent(Voice.this,TranslateActivity.class);
        a.putExtras(basket);
        startActivity(a); 
    }
}
```

TranslateActivity.java

```
package com.example.testing;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

//import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;
//import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;

public class TranslateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText etInput;
    EditText etOutput;
    TextToSpeech tts;
    String gotBread;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_translate);
    //    Translate.setClientId("d6159b31-37ba-4668-a31f-de0de6c47a38");
   //     Translate.setClientSecret("UMjSB3cHaSkLE+2xw4+a4dLIFahLdQQqh1YOhXdqfh4");
        Button Trans = (Button)findViewById(R.id.translate);
        etInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
        etOutput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output);
        Bundle gotBasket= getIntent().getExtras();
        gotBread=gotBasket.getString("key");
        etInput.setText(gotBread);
        Trans.setOnClickListener(this);
        tts =new TextToSpeech(TranslateActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(status !=TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                    Locale spanish = new Locale("es", "ES");
                    tts.setLanguage(spanish);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        //get the text entered      
                String In =etInput.getText().toString();
                String s[]=In.split(" ");
                //String out[]=  new String[3];
                String str=new String();
                String outString=new String();
                //String Out;
                try {
                    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
                         if(s[i].equals("who")){
                             str="whoa";
                            //etOutput.setText("whoa");
                            //str=etOutput.getText().toString();
                            //tts.speak(str,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);    
                        }else if(s[i].equals("are")){
                          //    etOutput.setText("arey");
                              str="arey";
                            //str=etOutput.getText().toString();
                            //tts.speak(str,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        }else if(s[i].equals("you")){
                         str="ram";

                            //etOutput.setText("your");
                            //str=etOutput.getText().toString();
                            //tts.speak(str,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        }   
                         outString+=str ;
                         outString+=" ";

                    }
                    tts.speak(outString,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                  //  String Out = Translate.execute(In, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.FRENCH);

               //   etInput.setText(Out);
        //        etOutput.setText(Out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
}
```

Logcat file is

```
04-19 02:36:07.140: D/dalvikvm(865): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-19 02:36:10.500: D/dalvikvm(865): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 4% free 2887K/3008K, paused 352ms, total 392ms
04-19 02:36:10.550: I/dalvikvm-heap(865): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.722MB for 1920016-byte allocation
04-19 02:36:10.690: D/dalvikvm(865): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 4760K/4884K, paused 139ms, total 139ms
04-19 02:36:12.760: E/MediaPlayer(865): Should have subtitle controller already set
04-19 02:36:13.510: D/gralloc_goldfish(865): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-19 02:36:14.510: D/dalvikvm(865): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 12K, 2% free 4903K/4992K, paused 46ms, total 58ms
04-19 02:36:14.790: I/Choreographer(865): Skipped 123 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-19 02:36:15.250: I/Choreographer(865): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-19 02:36:48.400: I/Choreographer(865): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-19 02:36:48.660: D/dalvikvm(865): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 35K, 2% free 5580K/5692K, paused 46ms, total 80ms
04-19 02:36:48.880: D/AndroidRuntime(865): Shutting down VM
04-19 02:36:48.880: W/dalvikvm(865): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a91b90)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865): Process: com.example.testing, PID: 865
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testing/com.example.testing.Voice}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at com.example.testing.Voice.onCreate(Voice.java:30)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  ... 11 more
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  ... 24 more
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:774)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3788)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:234)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:777)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:146)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:142)
04-19 02:36:48.950: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  ... 27 more
04-19 02:43:25.430: D/dalvikvm(1152): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 4% free 2887K/3008K, paused 52ms, total 53ms
04-19 02:43:25.440: I/dalvikvm-heap(1152): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.722MB for 1920016-byte allocation
04-19 02:43:25.540: D/dalvikvm(1152): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 4760K/4884K, paused 92ms, total 93ms
04-19 02:43:26.170: E/MediaPlayer(1152): Should have subtitle controller already set
04-19 02:43:26.480: D/gralloc_goldfish(1152): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-19 02:43:27.510: D/dalvikvm(1152): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13K, 2% free 4904K/4996K, paused 74ms, total 75ms
04-19 02:43:28.260: I/Choreographer(1152): Skipped 106 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-19 02:43:29.220: I/Choreographer(1152): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-19 02:43:31.740: I/Choreographer(1152): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-19 02:43:32.100: D/dalvikvm(1152): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 39K, 2% free 5582K/5696K, paused 91ms, total 98ms
04-19 02:43:32.230: D/AndroidRuntime(1152): Shutting down VM
04-19 02:43:32.230: W/dalvikvm(1152): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a91b90)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): Process: com.example.testing, PID: 1152
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testing/com.example.testing.Voice}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.example.testing.Voice.onCreate(Voice.java:30)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     ... 11 more
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     ... 24 more
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:774)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3788)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:234)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:777)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:146)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:142)
04-19 02:43:32.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     ... 27 more
04-19 02:43:35.530: I/Process(1152): Sending signal. PID: 1152 SIG: 9
04-19 03:37:08.367: D/dalvikvm(1288): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 60K, 5% free 2887K/3028K, paused 128ms, total 131ms
04-19 03:37:08.387: I/dalvikvm-heap(1288): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.722MB for 1920016-byte allocation
04-19 03:37:08.507: D/dalvikvm(1288): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 4760K/4904K, paused 113ms, total 113ms
04-19 03:37:09.197: E/MediaPlayer(1288): Should have subtitle controller already set
04-19 03:37:09.437: D/gralloc_goldfish(1288): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-19 03:37:10.757: D/dalvikvm(1288): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13K, 2% free 4904K/4996K, paused 66ms, total 71ms
04-19 03:37:11.517: I/Choreographer(1288): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-19 03:41:05.367: D/dalvikvm(1288): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 31K, 2% free 5551K/5660K, paused 58ms, total 68ms
04-19 03:41:05.447: D/dalvikvm(1288): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1919K, 32% free 4442K/6476K, paused 39ms, total 40ms
04-19 03:41:05.507: I/Choreographer(1288): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-19 03:41:08.277: D/dalvikvm(1288): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1354K, 44% free 3648K/6476K, paused 81ms, total 91ms
04-19 03:41:08.887: I/Choreographer(1288): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-19 03:41:09.337: I/Choreographer(1288): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-19 03:41:11.677: D/AndroidRuntime(1288): Shutting down VM
04-19 03:41:11.677: W/dalvikvm(1288): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a91b90)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288): Process: com.example.testing, PID: 1288
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH (has extras) }
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at com.example.testing.Voice.onClick(Voice.java:45)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-19 03:41:11.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 03:41:15.627: I/Process(1288): Sending signal. PID: 1288 SIG: 9
04-19 03:41:18.407: D/dalvikvm(1316): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 65K, 5% free 2945K/3088K, paused 34ms, total 37ms
04-19 03:41:18.407: I/dalvikvm-heap(1316): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.553MB for 635812-byte allocation
04-19 03:41:18.457: D/dalvikvm(1316): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3563K/3712K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
04-19 03:41:18.777: I/Choreographer(1316): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-19 03:41:18.797: D/gralloc_goldfish(1316): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: @kalyanpvs posted logcat error...but I don't think it will help as Recognizerintent doesn't work in virtual device and it can't get past that..........

Comment: How you are adding items in list view..?? by using List or array pass that particular item from `onItemClickListener` using position(in your code `int arg2` ) it will works